# How to send Private Message using privatemsg_services module?

Tags: privatemsg

I am using [privatemsg services module](https://github.com/deminy/privatemsg_services) to create REST API of [privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) using [Services Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) in Drupal 7.

I need to know how to send message and how to reply to a message ? Please tell me URL where i should send POST request and the Body of request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

To send new  message

**Endpoint:** http://example.com/services/privatemsg

**Content to Send (JSON Format)** :

```
{
   "recipients": "xxx",
   "subject":"xxx",
   "body":"xxxx"
}
```

To reply a message for particular chat thread

**Endpoint:** http://example.com/services/privatemsg

```
{
"thread_id": "xxx",
"subject": "xxx",
"recipients":"xxx",
"body":"xxx"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked but can you please tell me how to get recipients name ? For example I am trying to send message to Krishna and I don't know complete name so when I enter "@kri" it should give me suggestion of user names starting with "kri" ?

Comment: I have asked a new question with more explanation hope I can get answer from you. Here is URL :
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207180/how-to-load-username-to-send-private-message-using-privatemsg-services-module